# Android Java - Download Manager not saving using correct name

Tags: java, android

Almost everything is working correctly but when I download my file under "Downloads" it is saved as "Download-1"

Here is the code im using.

```
 public void download(){
    if (_ctx.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        DownloadManager.Request request = new  DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(link));
        request.setDescription("Downloading " + DisplayName +".mp3");
        request.setTitle(DisplayName +".mp3");
        request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_ONLY_COMPLETION);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "");
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)_ctx.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }
}
```

How can i get to use my custome title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

I got it to work by changing this:

`request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "");`

to

`request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, item.DisplayName +".mp3");`

This might help someone.